# Does Slack provide support for IP Whitelisting?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have an endpoint which I would like to dedicate it to requests originating from slack via Outgoing Webhooks.

Do we have IP addresses or CIDR block to provide IP whitelisting?

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759599/slack-webhook-which-ips-should-i-open but I am more worried about pinging my endpoint and bringing it down.

Comment: I would advise against using outgoing webhooks. Its deprecated and may deactivated completely in the near future. Use Events or RTM API instead.Source: https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK Slack is supporting IP whitelisting for requests from your app to Slack, but not the other way around as you are asking. ([Source](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-safety#ip_whitelisting))

However, Slack has a mechanism for verifying that a request from Slack is legit. So if your aim is to ensure that your endpoint is only used by request from Slack than check out [Signed Secrets](https://api.slack.com/docs/verifying-requests-from-slack).